# Nancy - Super Simple View Engine: How do I override a MasterPage's title in the view?

Tags: nancy

I would like to set the *title* of each rendered page from the corresponding view. I would also like a default title to be set in my Master page. Here is the super-simple set up I am using.

**Master Page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>NancyFX is Splendid</title>
</head>
<body>
    @Section['Content']
</body>
</html>
```

**View**

```
@Master['_Master']
@Section['Content']
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>Hello @Model.UserName</p>
@EndSection
```

I have tried a few of the more obvious guesses but no joy so far. Can you help?

On a more general note - is there any definitive help for Nancy's SSVE? I have read all the docs available on the site and GitHub but they are sparse. Just a list of all SSVE '@[]' keywords, would save me a lot of time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just render it from the model, same as anything else:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Hello @Model.Name!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Super Simple View Engine</h1>
<p>This text is in the master page, it has access to the model:</p>
<p>Hello @Model.Name!<p>
@Section['Content']
</body>
</html>
```

As for documentation, most of the tags are documented here: https://github.com/grumpydev/SuperSimpleViewEngine although it's slightly out of date now. It was initially designed purely for internal use, but obviously you are welcome to use it if you want to. The best place to look if you get stuck is the tests, there's samples for all the tags in there.

Comment: The Master page has access to the view model eh? Now that is clever and pretty much explains why I cannot find help for all the myriad keywords you would need if this wasn't so :-) Thanks. I am off and running now.