# Accessing Super simple view engine master page in Nancy?

Tags: nancy

I have specific requirement for project I am working on. I like to change CSS and attributes of master page from the Server side. I want change theme of the application.

[Nancy - Super Simple View Engine: How do I override a MasterPage's title in the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922691/nancy-super-simple-view-engine-how-do-i-override-a-masterpages-title-in-the)

After checking this, I got way how to override properties of Master page. I am using Nancy as web framework and Super simple view engine. Which is default with Nancy. Here as per previous link I need to pass theme attribute with every view model I am passing to the view.

So, my question is, that is there any way other than this? Means I directly access database to check current user setting for theme and render it and my core application part stays intact.

Please let me know if any further details needed.

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking. The linked post shows you how to use properties from your ViewModel in your Master page. Is there a reason that passing the theme on the ViewModel is not practical? I typically have a BaseViewModel that contains common properties like this.

Comment: Thanks got it... I was thinking of that... But not sure that I should do that or not... Thanks a lot for your answer. I am exactly asking that only.

Comment: @ChrisSainty hey its little bit late but still if you can move your comment to answer section so I can close the question. Obviously if you don't mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reworded from comments...
The linked post shows you how to use properties from your ViewModel in your Master page.
You can just pass the theme details along in a similar manner.
I typically do this with a BaseViewModel that contains common properties.